# How to keep a cell selected when NSFetchedResultsChangeMove is called with 2 identical NSIndexPath?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

If I click on a cell and a background Core Data refresh happens, my cell gets deselected.

After investigation, my `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`'s implementation of `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` gets called with a type of `NSFetchedResultsChangeMove` but `indexPath` and `newIndexPath` are identical (i.e. same row/section values).

The `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate` type doesn't get called.

My implementation of `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` is the typical one provided in Apple's documentation. I believe that switching from:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    ...

    switch(type) {

        ...

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```

to:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    ...

    switch(type) {

        ...

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            if (indexPath.section != newIndexPath.section || indexPath.row != newIndexPath.row) {
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

would solve my problem.

My question is: is this fix correct or do I miss something that could explain why my update is of the `NSFetchedResultsChangeMove` type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was that I was assigning values to `NSManagedObject` instances that were the same as before. i.e., if `foo.bar` was 2, I would call the API and call a new `foo.bar = 2` assignment on my object. Even though, values were identical, Core Data was still considering the value had changed.

It is still weird that I got a `NSFetchedResultsChangeMove` type instead of a `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate` type but heh.

What I did to resolve this is:

```
if ([object.changedValues count] == 0) {
    // Reverting changed on object
    [context refreshObject:object mergeChanges:NO]
}
```

At the end of each update, rather than comparing attributes one by one.